# json_normalize to split multiple json object: python

Tags: python, json, pandas

I have a json response like this

```
order_response = {
"orders": [
    {
        "id": '1',
        "email": "b@mail.com",
        "location_id": 9,
        "line_items": [
            {
                "id": 5,
                "product_id": 6,
            }, {
                "id": 7,
                "product_id": 8,
            }
        ]
    }, {
        "id": '2',
        "email": "b@mail.com",
        "location_id": 10,
        "line_items": {
            "id": 3,
            "product_id": 4,
        }
    },
]

}
```

And I wanted the output like this

```
id email      location_id line_items_id line_items_product_id
1  b@mail.com 9           5             6
1  b@mail.com 9           7             8
1  b@mail.com 10          3             4
```

I want to split the rows as per the number of objects in the line_items.
So my approach is to use the `json_normalize` feature of Pandas
I am able to spilt if I specify the column names in the code as shown below.

```
pd.io.json.json_normalize(report_json, ['line_items'], ['id', 'email'], record_prefix='line_items_')
```

but there may be other columns apart from `id, email`. I want this to be dynamic i.e. it should be able to do with any number of objects provided without explicitly defining 
Any help in this regard is highly appreciated.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First add list to one element dictionaries and also extract all keys of dictionaries:

```
L = []
keys = []
for x in report_json['orders']:
    d = {}
    for k, v in x.items():
        if isinstance(v, dict) and k =='line_items':
            d[k] = [v]
        else:
            d[k] = v
        if k !='line_items':
            keys.append(k)
    L.append(d)

print (L)
```

---

```
[
    {
        "id": '1',
        "email": "b@mail.com",
        "location_id": 9,
        "line_items": [
            {
                "id": 5,
                "product_id": 6,
            }, {
                "id": 7,
                "product_id": 8,
            }
        ]
    }, {
        "id": '2',
        "email": "b@mail.com",
        "location_id": 10,
        "line_items": [{
            "id": 3,
            "product_id": 4,
        }]
    }
]
```

---

```
from pandas.io.json import json_normalize

#get unique keys and pass to json_normalize
L1 = list(set(keys))
print (L1)
['location_id', 'id', 'email']

df = json_normalize(L,  ['line_items'],  L1, record_prefix='line_items_')
print (df)
   line_items_id  line_items_product_id  location_id id       email
0              5                      6            9  1  b@mail.com
1              7                      8            9  1  b@mail.com
2              3                      4           10  2  b@mail.com
```

Comment: This is the question, I dont want to explicitly define the column name(id, email), I want all the columns provided in the json response, it may be 1000 thats why I dont want to define it in the code.

Comment: @NikhilGupta - Can you check edit? You can get dynamically all values in list and pass to `json_normalize`

Comment: yes it worked, thanks man. this will be the last question. what if in some cases line_items is dictionary instead of list. how to troubleshoot that?

Comment: @NikhilGupta - It is list if multiple values and dict if one value like in question, not like in my data?

Comment: thanks buddy, it worked. just a small update, keys variable is undefined. it needs to be initialized and k should be appended to it in the for loop. Thank you so much